# iOS adding second animation to already animated UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I have a UIView called *waves* and it has a nice endless "floating" animation

```
  [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{

                     CGPoint center = waves.center;
                     center.y += 5;
                     waves.center = center;

                 } 
                 completion:nil];
```

Now if I add another animation, say moving this view to a different location, "floating" animations stops. It's a reasonable reaction and it's no problem to start the "floating" again in the completion block. I was just wondering if I'm missing something, perhaps in animation Options, to combine the two in a way that doesn't interrupt one another.

I was able to do so if the second animation is based on CGAffineTransfromScale, they combine no problem, but when I move the centre of the view it's not the case.

**UPDATE:** found a bug in performance. I have a button that calls the method responsible for moving the center of my View with animation. If I press it too fast before previous animation completed View just snaps into new position without animation and completion block is not called. Here's the code for that method:

```
- (void)wavesAnimationReversed:(BOOL)reversed {

    CGFloat y = waves.frame.size.height*0.25;
    y = reversed ? -y : y;
    // CGFloat damping = reversed ? 1 : 0.65;
    CGFloat damping = 1;    

    [UIView animateWithDuration:kWAVES_ANIMATION_DURATION
                          delay:0
         usingSpringWithDamping:damping
          initialSpringVelocity:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{

                         CGPoint center = waves.center;
                         center.y += y;
                         waves.center = center;

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [self handleStartWavesFloating];
                     }];
}
```

Comment: What about the `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` flag?

Comment: @GuyKogus nope, doesn't do the trick

Comment: Regarding your update, if you don't want the snap to occur then check if `finished` is true (or `YES`, rather). Also, if animating the transforms works then why not try using `CGAffineTransfromTranslate` in the animation block?

Comment: If you don't want that to happen, disable the button and as @GuyKogus suggests use the completion block to enable it again.

Comment: @wolffan yup, that's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform multiple animations you should use animateKeyFrames.
That being said you can't animate something that is being animated (your description matches perfectly what will happen). That is, because the values from your view are already changed (it's real values), the animation happens  out of your control.

Therefore, if you create a new animation, the default values are the end values of your first animation, when the 2nd animation triggers, it will automatically move the view to the new location to start the second animation.

Comment: I believe this is correct, the only reason you can combine scale and move animations is that they change different properties of object's frame.

Comment: @NKorotkov this is true, but if you do, you do inside the same UIView animation block.